# Check Modest number. How to include criteria where numLen<1 ---> return number cannot be split"

Tags: python

Here's the definition of [*Modest Number*](https://www.numbersaplenty.com/set/modest_number/).

> A number  *n*  is called modest if its digits can be separated into two numbers  *a*  and  *b*  such that  *n*  divided by  *b*  gives  *a*  as remainder.
> For example, 2851111 is modest because divided by 1111 gives 285 as remainder.

Here's an example which I considered:
is_modest(21333) ➞ True 
Combination 1: Left = 2 | Right = 1333 21333 % 1333 = 5 != Left 
Combination 2: Left = 21 | Right = 333 21333 % 333 = 21 = Left 
At least a combination satisﬁes the condition

Below is what I tried:

```py
def isModest(num):
    
    numStr = str(num)
    numLen = len(numStr)

    while numLen > 1:
        for i in range(1, numLen):
            rem = num % (int(numStr[i:])) # 5, 21, 15, 0
            if rem == int(numStr[:i]):
                return True
        else:
            return False
        
print(isModest(2036)) <br>
print(isModest(3412)) <br>
print(isModest(21333)) <br>
print(isModest(8)) #??? <br>
```

Comment: Why would you make a special case of single digit numbers ?  They are simply not modest and should return False like all other non-modest numbers.  That kind of special case just makes your function harder to use and provides no useful benefit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use string manipulations. Dividing by powers of 10 will do it more efficiently

```
def isModest(N):
    if N<10: return "cannot split"
    p10 = 10
    while p10 < N:
        a,b = divmod(N,p10)
        if b and N%b == a: return True
        p10 *= 10
    return False

for n in range(1,100):
    if isModest(n) is True: print(n)

13
19
23
26
29
39
46
49
59
69
79
89
```

Comment: no reason except that its one way I understand how to solve the question at the moment. it takes me awhile to understand splitting with powers of 10 as a path to solution as well. Thank you Alain !